# ruby 2.0 undefined method ObjectSpace.trace_object_allocations

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.0, objectspace

tried this on ruby 2.0.0 / 247 or head:

```
require 'objspace'
ObjectSpace.trace_object_allocations -> undefined method `trace_object_allocations' 
for ObjectSpace:Module
```

Docs say it should work http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/objspace/rdoc/ObjectSpace.html any idea what I'm missing ?

Comment: Probably included in not yet released version/patchlevel. http://svn.ruby-lang.org/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/trunk/ChangeLog?view=markup&pathrev=40957

Answer (score 4):

For higher ruby versions you still may get errors like:

```
undefined method `memsize_of' for ObjectSpace:Module
```

To solve this issue -> You need to `require 'objspace'`. According to https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/objspace/rdoc/ObjectSpace.html#method-c-memsize_of

Answer (score 2):

Only available when installing ruby-head aka ruby 2.1

Answer (score 0):

From the output of `puts ObjectSpace.methods.sort` after requiring `objspace`, it looks like that method doesn't exist.

```
irb(main):005:0> puts ObjectSpace.methods.sort
...
reachable_objects_from
remove_class_variable
remove_instance_variable
respond_to?
send
singleton_class
singleton_methods
 taint
tainted?
tap
to_enum
to_s
trust
undefine_finalizer
untaint
untrust
untrusted?
=> nil
irb(main):009:0> ObjectSpace.methods.include? :trace_object_allocations
=> false
```

You can see that it contains the `::reachable_objects_from` method, which is mentioned in the docs, but not the one you're looking for, unfortunately.